# How can I show contextual links on my node's full content view mode?

Tags: navigation

I need to be able to display my contextual links in the node full content view mode. How can I achieve this? Maybe something in my node.tpl?

Comment: you want to display contextual links for nodes or for a view page?

Comment: I want to use it for nodes. I have revised my question to remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show contextual link on a node view 
try out this code on your custom module file.

```
function mymodulename_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  $node = $build['#node'];
  if (!empty($node->nid)) {
    $build['#contextual_links']['node'] = array('node', array($node->nid));
  }
}
```

Comment: Anyway of printing this in the tpl without having to make and enable a simple module to achieve this?

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/951088#comment-4350170 worked for me with few css changes to make the link display as block on mouse hover.the code needs to be placed at template.php of your theme